# c++ compile error in priority_queue template

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following class like to used in priority_queue :

```
class People
{
public  :
    People(int iage,char *n)
    {
        age = iage ;
        strcpy(name,n) ;
    }
    bool operator >(People& m)
    {
        return( (this->age) >  m.getage() ) ;
    }
    int getage() {return age;}
    char* getname() {return name;}
private :
    int age ;
    char name[28] ;
} ;
```

The priority_queue is like :

```
template <typename T>
class Compare{
public:
    bool operator()(const pair<T,int> &lhs,const pair<T,int> &rhs) const{
       //return ((lhs.first) > (rhs.first)) ;
       T t1 = lhs.first ;
       T t2 = rhs.first ;
       return (t1 > t2) ;
   }
} ;

template <typename T>
vector<T> merge_arrays(const vector<vector<T> > &S)
{
    priority_queue<pair<T,int>,vector<pair<T,int> >,Compare<T> > min_heap;
    ......
}
```

In main() :

```
int main()
{
    vector<People> v1 ;
    vector<People> v2 ;
    vector<People> v3 ;
    vector<vector<People> > vx ;
    char namex[3][20] = {"People1","People2","People3"} ;

    for(int idx=0;idx<30;idx++)
    {
        if( (idx%3)==0)
            v1.emplace_back(idx,namex[0]) ;
        else if( (idx%3)==1)
            v2.emplace_back(idx,namex[1]) ;
        else
            v3.emplace_back(idx,namex[2]) ;
    }//for

    vx.push_back(v1) ;
    vx.push_back(v2) ;
    vx.push_back(v3) ;

    vector<People> v = merge_arrays<People>(vx) ;
    ....
}
```

The question is in Compare ,  the original source is :

```
template <typename T>
class Compare{
public:
    bool operator()(const pair<T,int> &lhs,const pair<T,int> &rhs) const{
       return ((lhs.first) > (rhs.first)) ;
   }
} ;
```

This will have compiled error  ,  So I change this source to the following and works!!

```
template <typename T>
class Compare{
public:
    bool operator()(const pair<T,int> &lhs,const pair<T,int> &rhs) const{
       T t1 = lhs.first ;
       T t2 = rhs.first ;
       return (t1 > t2) ;
   }
} ;
```

Although problem gone , still I like to know if anything else I can do for this test 
so that no need to  T t1 = lhs.first ;   and  T t2 = rhs.first ;  and still make this function works !!!!

Any comments,suggestions are appreciated !!

Comment: random idea...what if you cast lhs.first and rhs.first to (T)lhs.first and (T)rhs.first..and do something like return (T)lhs.first > (T)rhs.first? just a guess no guarantees :)

Comment: @Josh , thanks ,add (T) still get compile error !

Comment: weird...I have been staring at it and I have no other ideas lol

Comment: It's a long shot but try: `return lhs.first > rhs.first ;`

Comment: @Smac89 , modify return ((lhs.first) > (rhs.first)) ; to return lhs.first > rhs.first ; get compiled error ! it is in g++ 4.4.6

Comment: What was the compiler error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operator isn't `const`, nor is its parameter. Both need to be.

Note the type of the objects being passed to your comparator:

```
const std::pair<T,int>& lhs, const std::pair<T,int>& rhs
```

Your `lhs.first > rhs.first` is only valid if your `operator >` is also `const`. Declare your operator like this:

```
bool operator >(const People& m) const
{
    return age > m.age ;
}
```

Also note your other members should likely also be const, as they are not intended to modify the object in any way. Declaring them as `const` ensures you do not accidentally modify the object while invoking them. I.e:

```
int getage() const { return age; }
const char* getname() const { return name; }
```

Best of luck.